# Derivation of matrix derivative

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, derivative

In the ML lecture notes of cs229, I am not able to derive the equation 3 in matrix derivatives. I applied the equation 1 to derive it, considering the product after A as another matrix, I am not getting the sum and am getting only the second term in the sum given as the derivative. How can I use equation 1 to derive this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: (3) has two terms involving $A$, so you cannot treat $BA^TC$ as a constant matrix and apply (1)

Comment: Oh, yeah, now I see the mistake in my approach. Thanks a lot. Can you maybe hint at how I can proceed to actually derive (3)?